# what does this java error mean?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to convince Zucker Reports to display a Jasper report but am getting a Java error and I don't speak java-ese.  I see that there is a file not found error, but I can't figure out which file is not found.  I replaced the long classpath with <SNIP>.

```
error compiling report report2.jrxml - cmdline: javaw -classpath "<SNIP>" 
at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperCompileMain D:\Program Files\sugarcrm-5.2.0e\php\tmp\php83.tmp modules/ZuckerReports/resources/report2.jasper 2>&1
JasperBatchMain :: compiling jasper design D:\Program to Files\sugarcrm-5.2.0e\php\tmp\php83.tmp
JasperBatchMain :: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program (The system cannot find the file specified)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program (The system cannot find the file specified)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:152)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:150)
at at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperCompileMain.main(JasperCompileMain.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:167)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a space in your file path. Enclose it in double quotes.

Possibly in the <SNIP> part. Try placing your files outside of `Program Files`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this bit of the error message:

> compiling jasper design **D:\Program** to
>   **Files\sugarcrm-5.2.0e\php\tmp\php83.tmp**

It's taken the filename with a space in and interpreted it as two separate arguments.

Either quote the filename or (possibly simpler) move everything to a directory without a space in the name.

Comment: Or use DOS filenames, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

What program did you use to generate the JasperReports file report2.jrxml? iReport? My guess is that your iReport is too new, the JasperReports engine came with ZuckerReports is quite old. Try use an older version of iReport instead.